# How can I check the last modified date of the pdf present on the website without downloading it?

Tags: pdf, last-modified

I am checking the headers for getting the last modified date for pdf present on a website. But the thing is, when I am actually downloading the file and checking the document properties, I am getting the different last modified date.
So is there any way to get that last modified date without downloading the files?

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: "I am checking the headers", you mean HTML headers? "checking the document properties", yes PDF files have their own metadata including last modified date, which is what document properties would show. "So is there any way to get that last modified date without downloading the files?" Are you looking for a server side solution, or client side? Why is knowing the last modified date without downloading important anyway?

Comment: Yes, with "checking the headers", I mean HTML headers. I am looking for client side solution. and based on the last modified date(new version of pdf file uploaded), we will go ahead and download the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that data using a HEAD request, e.g.

```
curl -I https://www.cca.edu/sites/default/files/pdf/08/word-to-pdf.pdf 2>/dev/null | grep Last-Modified
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 09:37:07 GMT
```

Comment: Thanks @John Auld, but if you download the pdf file mention above and check the  properties (Ctrl+D), you will find some different modified date there. Is there any way that I can get the date mentioned in the document properties, without downloading the pdf?

Comment: Sadly, no. Since the Last-Modified header relates to a property of the file system.